# Connect Apple TV iPad Air and hotel wifi

Tags: appletv, ipad

Have iPad Air Apple TV 3rd generation and wireless internet at hotel but cannot get Apple TV to connect cause no login page to accept hotel agreement

Comment: I use a travel router.  That failed me recently tho, because the hotel was all wifi and had no wired Ethernet in the room.  I especially like the travel router tho, plug it in and all the devices are already set to join the travel routers wifi and I have a full local network for file transfers or streaming.   I haven't looked yet to see if there are travel routers that use a second radio to receive wifi, so that you could still use it in the case mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try authenticating with the iPad, then mirroring its screen to the Apple TV.  This won't give you access to AppleTV content, but will give you the big screen experience.

Comment: How do you authenticate iPad Air

Comment: To authenticate iPad simply connect to WiFi and try to navigate via Safari. If the hotel router is compliant with the standard login method it will prompt for login credentials via popup into Safari.